# Phonegap running Tensorflow

Tags: cordova, tensorflow

I'm new into the ML Scene and I want to create a phonegap app involving Tensorflow but I'm unsure where to start or if this is even possible. Can anyone give me a hand (Probably by linking me to some resources)? My app will just use tensor flow image recognition (probably pre-trained).

Thanks, Felix.
(This is a repost of this same question in the data science category which failed to garner a response)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a plugin that I've been working on:

https://github.com/heigeo/cordova-plugin-tensorflow

Comment: NICE! I'll be sure to have a look at it!

Comment: I'm having slight issues with getting any results from your plugin. Would you be able to give me a hand?

Comment: Sure, feel free to open a ticket on the repository.

Comment: @s-andrew-sheppard I'm NectarineGames by the way, and you solved my first issue, but now when I download the zipped files I get this error no matter what I try: index.html:1 Uncaught (in promise) Problem reading label file! I posted all the code on github: https://github.com/heigeo/cordova-plugin-tensorflow/issues/2. Would you be able to help me?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to create a phonegap app involving Tensorflow but I'm unsure where to start or if this is even possible

It's possible because you can run TensorFlow models on e.g. [Android](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android) and [iOS](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/ios_examples). For other platforms you'll first have to check that TensorFlow is supported.

However, since I'm not aware of any Cordova wrappers, [you may have to write those yourself](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/), so that your Cordova app can access those functions on the native platform.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm not going to mark your answer as the answer as I want to see what responses I will get! You'll most likely get the answer though.